# Get the id, not the object in a ManyToOne relationship to send it from an API Rest

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, webix

I've got an entity I send in a datatable (webix) thanks to an API rest. In this entity I have several ManyToOne relationeships which I don't know how to display or edit.

In my datatable, when I try to display the field which is in a relathinship I've got this instead of the id

```
[object Object]
```

When I try to edit this field by adding the id I've got this error message

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to ErpBundle\Entity\Trial::setGSponsor() must be an instance of ErpBundle\Entity\Sponsor, string given
```

I understand what I get in my datatable is an object but I don't know how to get the Id of the name instead (and being able to chose it from the datatable).

Do I have to edit the getter? The repository?

I've tried to edit my getter like that but of course it's not working:

```
/**
* Get gSponsor
*
* @return \ErpBundle\Entity\Sponsor
*/
public function getGSponsor()
{

return $this->gSponsor->getId();
}
```

Below a part of my code:

In the controller, I'm just rendering the template for the view. Webix just take the url as an argument to get the data (url: "rest->{{ path('erp_trialapi_cgetload') }}") The datatable is displayed automatically from what I send in my ApiController

**Part of my entity**

```
class Trial
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;     

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ErpBundle\Entity\Sponsor")
 */
private $gSponsor;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set gSponsor
 *
 * @param \ErpBundle\Entity\Sponsor $gSponsor
 *
 * @return Trial
 */
public function setGSponsor(\ErpBundle\Entity\Sponsor $gSponsor = null)
{
    $this->gSponsor->get = $gSponsor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get gSponsor
 *
 * @return \ErpBundle\Entity\Sponsor
 */
public function getGSponsor()
{

    return $this->gSponsor;
}
```

**My API**

```
class TrialApiController extends FOSRestController
{
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/api_t/get")
 */
public function cgetLoadAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('ErpBundle:Trial');
    $trials = $repo->findAll();
    return $trials;
}
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly you doing in the Controller? Also change the setter inner to `$this->gSponsor = $gSponsor`, you just save the Entity Object. If the relations are correct, it will automatically take the needed parameters. When you want something to read, you just get the Object and call the getter methods. `$gSponsor->getName();` etc.

Comment: findAll(); don't return an object but an array of object. You can do a `for` to each of your object in your trials lists and for each one of them do `->getId();` put all of the id you get in an array and then return this array

Comment: In the controller, I'm just rendering the template for the view. Webix just take the url as an argument to get the data (url: "rest->{{ path('erp_trialapi_cgetload') }}") The datatable is displayed automatically from what I send in my ApiController. I'd like to do something like $gSponsor->getName() in the ApiController, but as you see, it just take all the data from my entity with the findAll method.

Comment: So itterate trought the array and call the getter methods. If you did `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` you should have all necessary methods for that.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, it's working with the loop, but is there any other way to do it, in another part of the code (like in the getter)? Because I have like 80 fields in 4 tables and it will kind of annoying to do it for all of them :).